# Auto login windows security window

Tags: vb.net

I try to fill up automatically the name and the password for a windows security window, basically the page is opening after a couple of seconds with the window but the fields for user and password are empty. This is the code I have so far, any help is appreciate. Thank you.

This is where I am now:

Dim oProcess As New Process()
        Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo

```
    psi.FileName = "arp"
    psi.Arguments = "-a"
    psi.UseShellExecute = False
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.CreateNoWindow = True
    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(psi)
    Dim s As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
     s = s.Split(" ".ToCharArray)(1)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://user:pass@" + (s) + ":34655/")
```

It works but I get from cmd only the first ip(192.2.2.2), if I don't use the arp command I don't see the ip of the device.
Basically I need to get the ip  from this cmd output from third row:
"interface: 192.2.2.2 ----0xb//////
internet address-   physical address---type///////
134.45.455.455.4(this ip)     mac address  dynamic//////
etc etc"/////
Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  You should research PInvoke - all those Longs are likely just Int32.  And since they are functions your code could test the return to see if and when they are failing - if they were used, that is,

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific.
If this site you are connecting to uses *Basic authentication*, you are presented with a System InputBox with standard fields and a button control. 
If it uses *WebForm LogIn* authentication, you are presented with a Web Form 
with semi-standard Form Elements to fill in.

In the former case, it is quite simple to perform an authentication throu `WebRequest/HttpWebResponse` or, if you really need to use a WebBrowser control,
to setup its `.Navigate` property to achieve the same result.

If your case is the latter, since you are using a WebBrowser control to navigate to an URI, you don't really need any PInvoke at all.
Mind that `WebBrowser.Document` contains the `HtmlDocument` that describes the HTML page.
It also lets you access all the object that the page defines.

So, if you know in advance which Site you are connecting to (ie, you need to perform this operation 
for this one Site only), you can use the `.DocumentCompleted` Event of your WebBrowser and set 
your parameters directly from there:

Consider:
`["UserName"], ["Password"], ["LoginButton"]`
as the IDs of the Html Elements that represent an `<input>` Textbox, an `<input>` Password,
and a `<input>` Button that forwards the form parameters in a .Click Event .
So, read from the Html Page the IDs of the elements in the form and just insert your values:

In WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All(["UserName"]).SetAttribute("Value", "UserID")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(["Password"]).SetAttribute("Value", "Password")
WebBrowser1.Document.All(["LoginButton"]).InvokeMember("Click")
```

I'm using `.Document.All` and `.Document.GetElementById` to show that there are two different 
methods to accomplish the same task.

If you don't know in advance what the content of the Html Page is, you need to perform a simple parsing of the page (using the HtmlDocument Object), retrieve the  elements of the form and then repeat the 
previous task.

As I said, you need to be more specific.
If you have questions, comment and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yes, is a basic authentication case. I managed to login eventually. The page is opening but as soon as I press a button inside of the page the authentication window comes back again so I have to input again the user and the password.

Comment: It's not clear how you managed to authenticate. Via HttpRequest POST?

Comment: What I mean is that Basic Authentication has a Level Rule. If you authenticate at an URI "https://servername/directory1/" you are authenticated only for some that is on the same level ie. "directory1". If you ask for something that il located in "https://servername/directory1/directory2/", you have to authenticate again for that level.

Comment: Ok, so now I can log with no other problems with this   WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://user:pass@169.254.105.222:6008/"). Now I cannot press a button inside, there is no id for that element. Any suggestions for this problem? Thank you

Comment: It depends. What are you really after? Pseudo-clicking random buttons? Do you want to Login to a page that a specific button redirects to? If the latter, just login to that page setting it in your URI. You should explain a bit better what is your purpose and why you chose this path (WebBrowser vs. HttpWebRequest authentication).

Comment: @user8967715 Maybe edit your question adding more details.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I figure out a way to press the button. I need to add the ip address from arp -a to user:pass@"ip from arp", this is the purpose of this. Sorry to jump like this but I am very new to this and I read a lot and try to figure out the path. Now I am stuck here, can you suggest a way to run cmd...arp -a then grab the first ip, interface:11.11.11.11 and copy over the web link instead of 169.254...?Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @user8967715 "I need to add the ip address from arp" is not a purpose, it's a mean to an end since it's not the final step. Are you trying to grab a default gateway address and then connect to it's http interface and edit something? When you define a starting point and a final destination clearly, the tools needed to get there become quite obvious. Take your time, edit your question with the details (maybe someone else will have a benefit from it).

Comment: Yes, I need to grab the default gateway of an interface that has a dynamic ip address, then connect through the http interface to apply changes. Because the ip may change next time when  the interface is powered up I need to be able to automatically change that so the http will open correctly.

Comment: Well, it's more clear. Now, if you edit your question adding the details of you task (avoid something like "_I need to use ARP_", because you really don't, you need the address of a router or the like), then show what you've got so far and I'll give you an answer.